# Finding the number of real roots in an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Say I have a polynomial like this one

$$3x^5 -10x^3 -120x +30 = 0$$
And I am asked to find the exact number of real roots.
I have tried  to use the Descartes' Rule of Signs, however, it gives the number of possible roots, but not the exact amount.
How can I solve this question and, in general, for all types of polynomials.
I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: What possibilities does Descartes' Rule of Signs give?

Comment: Do you know *Sturm's algorithm*?

Comment: The derivative is $15 (x-2) (x+2) \left(x^2+2\right)$, the sign of which is very easy to determine. Note $f(-\infty)=-\infty$, $f(-2)>0$, $f(2)<0$, $f(\infty)=\infty$.

Comment: $1.$ Is your question about this particular polynomial? $2.$ Is your question about these types of polynomial?( I.e. of degree 5, even power absent, or any random odd degree polynomial?)$ 3.$ You want to solve by hand or you can also use a computer program?

Comment: you can check $f'=0$ it has two roots , so you will have 1-maximum (+) , one minimum(-) ...so you will have $\bf{3}$ real roots

Comment: @Jaideep Khare , any polynomial, e.g power of 5 or 7, and I do need to solve them by hand. Thanks.

Comment: @Ruben If so, then do add this point in the main body of question, because you'll receive answers about this particular polynomial and it *may not* be applicable in all type of polynomials.

Comment: @Jaideep Khare , thanks, did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be a turning point between every two roots. The derivative is $15x^4-30x^2-120=15(x^2-4)(x^2+2)$. So there are only two turning points, at $x=\pm2$, and so at most three real roots. If both turning points are the same side of the $x$-axis there will be one root, and if they are on different sides there will be three, so you just need to check the heights of the two turning points.

Comment: thanks, this does make sense. Does this apply to any type of polynomial, e.g. of power 7?

Comment: @Ruben It applies to any polynomial, but it is only useful if it happens to be easy to find all the roots of the derivative. Here it is because the derivative happens to factorise nicely.

Comment: sorry to bother you again. And what to do when it does not factorise? Are there any other methods available, when solving without calculator?Thanks.

Comment: @Ruben: what's the meaning of "without calculator"? If you carefully plot a few hundred points by hand, you'll likely get an accurate picture of your polynomial. If you mean formulas, the absolute majority of polynomials of degree give and more have no formulas for their roots.

Answer (score 1):

First of all differentiate the function $f(x) = 3x^5 -10x^3 -120x + 30$:
$$f^{'}(x) = 15x^4 -30x^2 -120$$
Consider the equation $f^{'}(x) = 0$: 
$$15x^4 -30x^2 -120 = 0$$
$$x^4 - 2x^2 -8 = 0$$
$$(x-2)(x+2)(x^2 + 2) = 0$$ 
Hence, there are two turning points at $x = 2$ and $x = -2$.

Since $f^{'}(x) = 15(x+2)(x-2)(x^2 + 1)$, we can see that $f(x)$ is increasing on $x \le -2$ and on $x \ge 2$ and it's decreasing on $ -2 \le x \le 2$.

Hence, we have a local maximum at $x = -2$ and a local minimum at $x = 2$

Now, let's have a look at $f(-2)$ and $f(2)$: 
$$f(-2) = 254 > 0$$
$$f(2) = -194 <0$$

Overall, the graph of $f(x)$ would have to intercept with x-axis $3$ times judging by the coordinates of its local maximum and minimum.

Therefore, you have a total of $3$ real roots.